# How can I get all text nodes from XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I want to get all text nodes from an XML file.

How can I do this?

Example Input:

```
<root>
<slide>
<Image>hi</Image>
<ImageContent>this</ImageContent>
<Thumbnail>is</Thumbnail>
<ThumbnailContent>A</ThumbnailContent>
</slide>
</root>
```

Expected Output:

```
hi this is A
```

Comment: Use an XML Parser to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
        string input = @"
            <root>
                <slide>
                    <Image>hi</Image>
                    <ImageContent>this</ImageContent>
                    <Thumbnail>is</Thumbnail>
                    <ThumbnailContent>A</ThumbnailContent>
                </slide>
            </root>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
        //You can also load data from file by passing file path to Load method
        //XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");
        foreach(var slide in doc.Root.Elements("slide"))
        {
            var words = slide.Elements().Select(el => el.Value);
            string s = String.Join(" ", words.ToArray());
        }
```

Comment: Input is "XML File", No string

Comment: In that case you should use path to the file as a parameter to Load method.

Comment: @AML, please note that `doc.Root` can be null! Please see my answer: it has some additional checks.

Comment: @IvanG, the `words.ToArray()` call is not necessary. `string.Join()` method works with `IEnumerable<string>` just fine.

Comment: @Serge Have you tried `string s = String.Join(" ", words);` - it throws compiler error saying "Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'" because `String.Join` expects `string[]`, not `IEnumerable<string>`, it doesn't convert to string array implicitly.

Comment: @IvanG, it seems you're using .NET framework < 4.0. Please take a look at [string.Join method (.NET 4.0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

The only solution (so far) to enumerate all text nodes in any xml, regardless of its structure:

```
string input = @"
    <root>
        <slide>
            <Image>hi</Image>
            <ImageContent>this</ImageContent>
            <Thumbnail>is</Thumbnail>
            <ThumbnailContent>A</ThumbnailContent>
        </slide>
    </root>";

foreach (XText text in (IEnumerable)XDocument.Parse(input).XPathEvaluate("//*/text()"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(text.Value);
}
```

EDIT: if you want to load xml from file then use `XDocument.Load` instead.

Answer (score 3):

This code will print the inner text of all xml nodes which doesnt have a child:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
        x.Load("exp.xml");
        PrintNode(x.DocumentElement);
    }

    private static void PrintNode(XmlNode x)
    {
        if (!x.HasChildNodes)
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", x.InnerText));

        for (int i = 0; i < x.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            PrintNode(x.ChildNodes[i]);
        }
    }
```

On your example XML it will result in the output you want :)

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            XDocument xmlSkuDescDoc = XDocument.Parse
                (@"<root>
                                <slide>
                                <Image>hi</Image>
                                <ImageContent>this</ImageContent>
                                <Thumbnail>is</Thumbnail>
                                <ThumbnailContent>A</ThumbnailContent>
                                </slide>
                                </root> "
                ); 
             var result = (from data in xmlSkuDescDoc.Descendants("slide")
             select data).Elements().Select(i => i.Value).Aggregate((a, b) => a + " " + b); 
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

N.B.~  use `XDocument.Load(filename)` if loading from file

e.g.

```
string fileName = @"D:\MyXml.xml";
XDocument xmlSkuDescDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
```

.... and the rest follows as shown above

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using `XDocument` class (LINQ to XML). Assuming that you have exactly one **slide** element:

Using plain `XDocument` navigation:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("file path here");

if (doc.Root == null)
    throw new ArgumentException(); // No root node!
var slideElement = doc.Root.Element("slide");
if (slideElement == null)
    throw new ArgumentException(); // No slide node!

var values = string.Join(" ", slideElement.Elements().Select(element => element.Value));
```

Using XPath node selection:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("file path here");
var slideElements = doc.XPathSelectElements("root/slide/*");
var values = string.Join(" ", slideElements.Select(element => element.Value));
```